# (No implementation found for method _init on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, google-mobile-ads

couldnt find anything wrong with it

**dependencies:**

```
 google_mobile_ads: ^1.1.0
```

**Error:**

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
> MobileAds#initialize on channel plugins.flutter.io/google_mobile_ads)
> at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:5067:11)
> at platform_channel.MethodChannel.new._invokeMethod (http://localhost:58428/packages/flutter/src/services/restoration.dart.lib.js:1560:21)
> at _invokeMethod.next ()
> at http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:40571:33
> at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:40441:59)
> at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:35363:29)
> at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:35931:49)
> at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:35969:17)
> at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:35817:23)
> at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:35838:35)
> at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:40708:13)
> at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:40714:13)
> at http://localhost:58428/dart_sdk.js:36191:9

**AdsManager :**

```
class AdsManager {
  static bool testMode = true;

  late InterstitialAd? interstitialAd;
  int numInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;

  static String get rewardedAdUnitId {
    if (testMode == true) {
      return RewardedAd.testAdUnitId;
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "ca-app-pub-1571703103044065/4157175333";
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return "ca-app-pub-1571703103044065/4157175811";
    } else {
      throw UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }

  static String get bannerAdUnitId {
    if (testMode == true) {
      return BannerAd.testAdUnitId;
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "ca-app-pub-1571703103044065/4157175333";
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return "ca-app-pub-1571703103044065/6858117501";
    } else {
      throw UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }

  static String get interstitialAdUnitId {
    if (testMode == true) {
      return InterstitialAd.testAdUnitId;
    } else if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return "ca-app-pub-1571703103044065/4157175333";
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return "ca-app-pub-1571703103044065/2885703588";
    } else {
      throw UnsupportedError("Unsupported platform");
    }
  }
}
```

**in page.dart**

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late RewardedAd _rewardedAd;
  late InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
  int numInterstitialLoadAttempts = 0;
  bool isRewardedAdReady = false;
  var _balance = 0;

  //Banner Ad

  late BannerAd _bannerAd;
  bool _adIsLoaded = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _initGoogleMobileAds();
    _loadRewardedAd();
    loadInterstitialAd();
    //
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
        adUnitId: AdsManager.bannerAdUnitId,
        request: const AdRequest(),
        size: AdSize.banner,
        listener: BannerAdListener(
          onAdLoaded: (ad) {
            setState(() => _adIsLoaded = true);
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
            setState(() => _adIsLoaded = false);
          },
        ));
    _bannerAd.load();
    //
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
```